# Unresponsive restore process for log shipped db having memory optimised tables

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, sql-server-2022

Log shipping documentation has a caution:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

> Known issue: For databases with memory-optimized tables, performing a
> transactional log backup with no recovery, and later executing a
> transaction log restore with recovery, may result in an unresponsive
> database restore process. This issue can also affect log shipping
> functionality. To work around this problem, the SQL Server instance
> can be restarted before initiating the restore process.

I have a log shipped db with memory optimized tables. So I'm preparing for this scenario.

1. `performing a transactional log backup with no recovery` - I'm assuming this is on the primary node and would be required only when doing the DR drill or during actual DR when the primary is still accessible
2. `later executing a transaction log restore with recovery` - I'm assuming this is on the secondary (DR) node and only to be done as part of DR drill or actual DR.

The above will result in unresponsive db restore process on the secondary.

The Microsoft solution is to restart SQL server services on the DR node and repeat the step 2 given above, and this they say will resolve the issue.

Have I understood this correctly.